# mesh / region creation in unit meters or mm:

Tags: plotting, finite-element-method, mesh, units

How can we know the unit of mesh or create a mesh in specified length units:

such as, for example I have:

```
    bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {1/6, 1/6}, {5/6,
       1/6}, {5/6, 5/6}}, 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 
        1}}], LineElement[{{5, 6}, {6, 7}}]}];
bmesh["Wireframe"]
```

How can I specify the length of the mesh and/or boundaries in meter or mm or cm units:

```
 mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, MaxCellMeasure -> Infinity];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

is there a way or am I missing some basics?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The numbers "Coordinates", without any unit,  define your mesh.

One way to get a mm-mesh : Introduce pseudo units `meter,mm`

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
meter=1; 
mm=meter/1000; 

bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[
"Coordinates" -> mm {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {1/6, 1/6}, {5/6, 1/6}, {5/6,5/6}}, "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3,4}, {4, 1}}], LineElement[{{5, 6}, {6, 7}}]}];
Show[bmesh["Wireframe"], Axes -> True]
```

[image]

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, MaxCellMeasure -> mm^2/100];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Hope it helps!